# Python Looping through txt files to create and merging Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

What’s the best way to create and then merge to an existing Dataframe in a loop?  I have a log file (say FILENAME1) which generates txt files giving me stats of interest. I have a script that loops through and opens each txt file and generates a DataFrame using pd.read_csv.  I then paste each Dataframe to Excel using xlsxwriter.

The problem I have is that each txt file is different to the next, added on to this when I do the same for the next file (FILENAME2) I am effectively starting from a clean slate.

For example eash Log file will generate say:

```
FILENAME1
Tech_Summary.txt
Error_Totals.txt
```

I then process these txt files in a loop (DataFrame them) and paste to Excel and delete once I am done.  Then the next file generates similar files with the same file name:

```
FILENAME2
Tech_Summary.txt
Error_Totals.txt
```

My loop needs work as I am overwriting the Dataframe each time I open a new txt file as the merge function isn’t working as I’d hoped.  But I am looking to merge each iteration generated Dataframe with the previous iteration dataframe... but on a per txt file basis

Here’s my attempt so far

```
#Outline Dict items (make it generic for expansion)
TextExtractor={

    "Tech":{'txtfileID':'Tech_Summary',
                'lineskip':16,
                'linegrab':3,
                'linesplit':'% of Time in |;',
                'all_cols_labled':[1,'Tech','Percent','Null'],
                'cols_grab':['Tech','Percent'],
                'container':[],
                },      

        """ SAMPLE OF DF CREATED for "Tech"
           Tech    Percent Iter         Filename
        0  Type1        0  Iteration_1  Tech
        1  Type2      100  Iteration_1  Tech
        2  Type3        0  Iteration_1  Tech
        """

    "Errors":{'txtfileID':'Error_Totals',
                'lineskip':19,
                'linegrab':13,
                'linesplit':';',
                'all_cols_labled':['Scheme','Tot Errors','Tot Count','Percentage'],
                'cols_grab':['Scheme','Tot Errors','Tot Count','Percentage'],
                'container':[],
                },  

        """ SAMPLE OF DF CREATED for "Errors"
               Scheme  Tot Errors  Tot Count  Percentage    Iter        Filename
        0        -1        0           0     0              Iteration_1  Errors
        1        -2        0           0     0              Iteration_1  Errors
        2        -3        0           0     0              Iteration_1  Errors
        3        -4        0           0     0              Iteration_1  Errors
        4        -5       97           0     0              Iteration_1  Errors
        5        -6       55           0     0              Iteration_1  Errors
        """
}

looprun = 0
for textfile in os.listdir(resdir):
    if textfile.endswith('.txt'):
        for key in TextExtractor:
            #Set out rows and cols for Excel
            txtxlcol = XL_TextFileCoords['COLUMN']
            txtxlrow = XL_TextFileCoords['ROW']

            if TextExtractor[key]['txtfileID'] in textfile:
                #open each txt file and grab the selected data to make dataframe (DF)
                txt = pd.read_csv(resdir+'\\'+textfile, skiprows=TextExtractor[key]['lineskip'], nrows=TextExtractor[key]['linegrab'], header=None, sep=TextExtractor[key]['linesplit'], names=TextExtractor[key]['all_cols_labled'], usecols=TextExtractor[key]['cols_grab'], engine='python')
                #make dataframe
                txtDF = DataFrame(txt)
                #add iteration column to differentiate between each FILENAME
                txtDF['Iter'] = pd.Series(logID, index=txtDF.index)
                #add key column to DF to know what text file the data is from
                txtDF['Filename'] = pd.Series(key, index=txtDF.index)
                #convert DF to list ready to drop into each key (txt file) for later processing                 
                converttolist = txtDF.set_index(txtDF.index).T.to_dict('list')
                #Drop converted DF data into [key]['container'] for each txt file type based on key
                TextExtractor[key]['container'].append(converttolist)

                #write DF to Excel file
                txtDF.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=logID,startrow=txtxlrow, startcol=txtxlcol,index=False, header=False, columns=TextExtractor[key]['cols_grab'])
                #...do excel plotting stuff here

        #remove txt files from directory ready for next FILENAME (Iteration)
        os.remove(resdir+"/"+textfile)
    else:
        pass

for key in TextExtractor:
    print TextExtractor[key]['container']
```

So at the moment I am putting the DataFrames into a list of dicts, but I am really looking for something like this sort of output.  But keeping the loop functionality above for expension

```
""" 
# FINAL DATAFRAME 1
Type    Iter        Percent
Type1   Iteration_1  0
        Iteration_2  100
        Iteration_3  0
Type2   Iteration_1  40
        Iteration_2  30
        Iteration_3  30
Type3   Iteration_1  15
        Iteration_2  55
        Iteration_3  30 

# FINAL DATAFRAME 2 
Scheme  Iter        Tot Errors  Tot Count  Percentage
-1      Iteration_1  0          5           30
        Iteration_2  0          5           12
        Iteration_3  7          7           12
-2      Iteration_1  7          9           18
        Iteration_2  6          0           9
        Iteration_3  5          2           17
-3      Iteration_1  5          4           17
        Iteration_2  6          1           12
        Iteration_3  9          6           21
-4      Iteration_1  8          7           18
        Iteration_2  4          8           12
        Iteration_3  4          3           84
-5      Iteration_1  3          2           91
etc...

"""
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In what sense do you want to "merge" the dataframes?  Do you want them to become part of one large dataframe?  That's what merging suggests, but the output you show has separate tables.

Comment: Hi ASGM, ideally i'd like to merge each dataframe based on txt file name, so yeah two dataframes if two txt files.  However with my loop solution i'm not sure this is possible, and may have to resort to one big dataframe.  Unfortunately I went along the loop path to make it more generic and easily expandable if I wanted to add more txt files later

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused - what do you mean by "merge" the dataframes if you still want two separate dataframes at the end of the process?  Two files, two dataframes - where is the merging taking place?

Comment: Hi ASGM. Apologies for the confusion. Basically I have a folder with several logs in it. I have a separate script that parses each log and in turn it generates txt files with useful information I'd like to grab.  I then in my sample code I loop through each txt file (say Tech_Summary.txt, and Error_Totals.txt) to generate a Dataframe and paste to Excel in the process. Finally i'll delete the txt files.  I'll move to the next log in the directory, parse to txt file again (again Tech_Summary.txt, and Error_Totals.txt), and repeat. So at the end of say 10 logs I am hoping to get two separate DFs

Comment: I should mention that I parse a log to txt, then loop through the txt files to create DFs, then delete the text files.  Then move on to the next log file in the directory, parse it to txt, loop through the new (but identically named) txt files again, delete them and so on.  Hope this makes sense?

Comment: How big are these files?  Is it feasible to read them all into memory at the same time, or is it important that each file be processed iteratively?

Comment: The files are huge unfortunately, 100MB+ each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: put each new DataFrame into a dictionary, with the iteration as the key.  Then merge them at the end.

---

I now think I understand what's going on.  You have a series of logs: `L1, L2 ... LN`.  From each log you extract two kinds of text files, `a` and `b`.  So you have `L1a, L2a ... LNa` and`L1b, L2b ... LNb`.  You want two DataFrames at the end, `dfa` and `dfb`.

I would start by extracting the code that makes a text file into a DataFrame and make it into its own function.  You don't need to add the `Iter` and `Filename` columns, because those are the same across the DataFrame and we'll take care of that information elsewhere.

```
def df_from_txt(resdir, textfile, key):
    txt = pd.read_csv(
         resdir+'\\'+textfile, 
         skiprows=TextExtractor[key]['lineskip'], 
         nrows=TextExtractor[key]['linegrab'], 
         header=None, 
         sep=TextExtractor[key]['linesplit'], 
         names=TextExtractor[key]['all_cols_labled'],  
         usecols=TextExtractor[key]['cols_grab'], 
         engine='python')
     return DataFrame(txt)
```

Now that the extraction logic is separated from the loop, it's easier to see the logic.  You also need to add a container dictionary to hold the results of your text file parsing.

```
dfs = {key: {} for key in TextExtractor.keys()}

for textfile in os.listdir(resdir):
    if textfile.endswith('.txt'):
        for key in TextExtractor:
            if TextExtractor[key]['txtfileID'] in textfile:
                df = df_from_txt(resdir, textfile, key)
                dfs[key][textfile] = df
```

Now you have a dictionary (`dfs`), whose keys are the different kinds of text files you extract from the logs (`"Tech"` and `"Errors"`).  The values are themselves dictionaries, where the keys are the names of the textfiles (if `textfile` is always the same, you can use some other value for the key - where does `logID` come from in your original function?).  All that remains is to merged the contents of the second-level dictionaries:

```
merged_dfs = {key: pd.concat(dfs[key]) for key in dfs.keys()}
```

Now you have a dictionary where the keys are still `"Tech"` and `"Errors"`, but the values are single DataFrames.

If this doesn't work, perhaps I've misinterpreted the structure of your data.  If you can post a simple working example, it would be easier to help.

Comment: Hi AGSM, apologies for the delayed reply, I have been on vacation these last two weeks.  Tried your solution today and it looks like it is working along the lines of what I was looking for.  Thanks for your help and advice.